# Have Google Chrome prioritize web history over bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

In Firefox, typing in the address bar prioritizes history over bookmarks:

[image]

But in Chrome, bookmarks are shown first:

[image]

Is there a way to get Chrome to follow Firefox's behavior?

Comment: And, actually, currently open tabs match even before bookmarks...

Comment: @Bandrami, that's true, but that's kinda nice so I don't mind.